# How to get the data/value size from CHAR column of Oracle Database?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table in Oracle DB with column **CHAR(11**).

I have inserted the value **'abcd '** to it. *(Note there is single space after abcd)*

When I do LENGTH(column) - it returns 11 instead of 5.

How do I get the data size instead of column size?

Reason I need it because I am reading the value from table1 *having CHAR datatype* and inserting the data to table2 *having VARCHAR datatype*.

So in this case, it adds 'abcd    '***(abcd with trailing 7 spaces)*** to table2 instead of 'abcd ' *(with single space).*

How do I avoid this? If I can get hold of data size from CHAR column then I can do that.

Please let me know how it can be achieved?

Comment: Can you add space values and expect them to count as length?

Comment: JFYI: According to Tom Kyte there exists no reason to ever use `CHAR` rather than `VARCHAR2`. Read here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063,

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `TRIM` with the default options will get rid of leading white-spaces and will not give the intended result most of the time. You either want `RTRIM` or use `TRIM` and specify `TRIM( TRAILING ' ' FROM column_name )`.

Comment: @MT0: Yes sorry, I already removed my misleading remark on `TRIM` when I read your answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a variable length column then use `VARCHAR2` and not `CHAR`.

---

A `CHAR` column is a fixed length string that will be right-padded with space (ASCII 32) characters. So, if you want the length of a `CHAR(11)` then it will always be 11 characters regardless of whether you tried to insert a 1-character or an 11-character string as it will be right padded.

If you want to ignore the right padding then `RTRIM` the string before measuring the length (however this will also remove any intentional trailing white spaces as well as the unintentional ones).

```sql
SELECT LENGTH( RTRIM( column_name ) ) FROM table_name
```

For example:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column_name CHAR(11) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( column_name )
  SELECT 'abcd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT ' abc' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT LENGTH( column_name ),
       LENGTH( TRIM( column_name ) ),
       LENGTH( RTRIM( column_name ) )
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

> ```
> LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) | LENGTH(TRIM(COLUMN_NAME)) | LENGTH(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME))
> ------------------: | ------------------------: | -------------------------:
>                  11 |                         4 |                          4
>                  11 |                         3 |                          4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dcefb67517f7251828b0d3bf40ad0281)*

As you can see, `LENGTH` on its own includes the entire padded string. Using `TRIM` gives the wrong answer as it also removes leading white-space as well as trailing white-space. `RTRIM` gives the correct length.

Answer (score -1):

Please try with trim .

select trim(column_name) from table;

Comment: What happens when column is `' abc'`?

Comment: Use ltrim for lest space and rtrim for right side space